# Updating Cinnamon causes Grub to freeze before the login screen

Tags: grub2, login

I have 3 HDDs and on /dev/sda1, I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed and also the bootloader is on the same disk.
After GRUB when I select Ubuntu 12.04 to boot up it freezes just after the GRUB screen and before the login screen.  Here is an image attached

[image]

This is how this problem started.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and I installed cinnamon, it was working fine, until I updated the Cinnamon. Cinnamon's new update had some problems and it used to freeze a lot while I was working on my computer.

So I read some solutions online, and they dictated me to downgrade the `xserver-common` package. I did that, and after downgrading the `xserver-common`, I restarted, and this is what turns up.

It just won't proceed forward from this screen. I need to restore it to fully functioning condition, since I have made a lot of changes on my Ubuntu 12.04 which take about 9 - 10 hours of work and I do not want to redo them. So, re-installation is not an option.

Is there anyway I can get my OS working again. Also would the recovery mode help.I edited my GRUB default files in `/etc/defaults/grub` for  not to display the recovery mode. So, if you can tell me how to boot up the recovery mode using GRUB CLI, that would be great.

Also note, I cannot access tty1 on that screen and there wasn't any response, doesn't matter which button I press.

After pressing shift, I tried the GRUB menu, it still looks like this

[image: grub screen after pressing shift]

**EDIT**

That worked perfectly. I upgraded, the xserver-common. And then booted up ubuntu, it booted up to the login screen. But then it freezes. On the login screen. I cannon move the cursor nor the keyboard works. I can see the Ubuntu login screen, but I cannot do any thing. I tried going back to recovery but it bring me back to the same screen. I also tried failsafe graphics mode and still it brings me back to the login screen where it gets stuck.

Comment: Did I understand you correctly when you say there is no recovery mode? If there is recovery mode you could reboot the computer and keep the SHIFT key pressed in order to access the boot options. Select "recovery mode". This should allow you to login in your system again.

Comment: Can you now enter into `tty1` or consoles by Pressing `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F1`?

Comment: No I tried it buy I cannot enter any tty

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the computer and keep the SHIFT key pressed in order to access the boot options.

- If you have the the "recovery mode" option then select it to boot and login your system.
- If there is no "recovery mode" option then you could follow these instructions ([GRUB2 How To Boot From CLI Mode](http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20How%20To%20Boot%20From%20CLI%20Mode.html))

Comment: It did not workout. The same GRUB menu was loaded after pressing shift. And also I had tried the CLI mode again, I was not able to boot it into recovery mode.

Comment: Here is what it looks like https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ewtkZqjSm_Y/UBOsUxc24jI/AAAAAAAAA5M/zh_NDqKpE4o/s1095/IMG_20120728_142516.jpg After pressing shift. I mean it looks the same, no recovery option.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instruction after you have the grub menu.

1. Press **`SHIFT`** key on that screen, select Ubuntu Entry by pressing **`Down`** Arrow Key.
2. Press **E** to enter into the Edit mood.
3. There will be a line with options `ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff`, remove these options by using **`backspace`** Key. **Don't delete the full line**.
4. And then write these new options in place of deleted options `ro recovery nomodeset`.
5. Then Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to boot into Ubuntu.

After booting into Ubuntu, upgrade the package `xserver-common` to resolve this issue. Since, You didn't ask question about your specific problem with Cinnamon's new updates, I thinks this answers your query.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I upgraded, the xserver-common. And then booted up ubuntu, it booted up to the login screen. But then it freezes. On the login screen. I cannon move the cursor nor the keyboard works. I can see the Ubuntu login screen, but I cannot do any thing. I tried going back to recovery but it bring me back to the same screen. I also tried failsafe graphics mode and still it brings me back to the login screen where it gets stuck.

Comment: @mihirk Try booting using the recovery mode. then Login. then downgrade the problematic package.